# Не работает преобразование строк на ардуино

Tags: c++, микроконтроллеры, arduino

Я хочу вывести какой - то параметр, который передаю в функцию, но, как я понимаю, во время преобразования `String` в `static char[]` происходит ошибка, потому что если явно указать значения в `str[]`, то всё будет работать.

```
void printWeb(const char &light)
{
  String tmp = 
  "HTTP/1.0 503 Service Unavailable\r\n"
  "\r\n"
  "<html>"
  "<body>"
  "The main server is currently off-line.<br />"
  + light;
  tmp = tmp +
  "</body>"
  "</html>";

  const char mr[sizeof tmp];
  tmp.toCharArray(mr, sizeof mr);
  const static volatile char str[] PROGMEM = {mr};

  memcpy_P(ether.tcpOffset(), str, sizeof str);
  ether.httpServerReply(sizeof str - 1);
}
```

P.S. Я не знаю, можно ли метки `C` и `C++` ставить для подобного вопроса, но вроде бы можно, это же считай `С++`

Comment: `const static volatile char str[] PROGMEM = {mr};` - что это вообще за язык программирования? Каким компилятором вы это смогли скомпилировать?

Comment: @AnT Всё кроме PROGMEM - чистый С++, а PROGMEM - модификатор переменных, добавляемый Arduino (это как бы свой язык, но по сути это С++ и фреймворк для работы с платами ардуино и им подобными)

Comment: @AnT http://microsin.net/programming/avr/arduino-build-process.html

Comment: Согласно описанию `PROGMEM`, это просто модификатор переменной. Он не меняет остальных правил синтаксиса и инициализации языка С++. В С++ нет и никогда не было возможности инициализировать один массив другим массивом (кроме строковых литералов в правой части). У вас же делается `... char str[] = {mr}`. Такой возможности в С++ нет и `PROGMEM` тут не помогает.

Comment: @AnT а, ну да, и в правду нет, прощу прощения

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сделал так, работает прекрасно:

```
 void printWeb(int openCount, int light, float temperature, float moisture)
{
  BufferFiller bf = ether.tcpOffset();
  bf.emit_p(PSTR(
              "HTTP/1.0 200 OK\r\n\r\n"
              "<html lang=\"ru\">"
              "<meta charset=\"UTF-8\">"
              "<body>"
              "<font size=\"6\">"
              "Вскрытий корпуса: $D<br>"
              "Уровень запылённости: $D %<br>"
              "Температура: $D &#x2103<br>"
              "Влажность: $D %<br>"
              "</font>"
              "</body>"
              "</html>"), openCount, 100 - (light - 26) / 10, static_cast<int>(temperature), static_cast<int>(moisture));

  ether.httpServerReply(bf.position());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Ну так оно и не будет работать. `const static char str[] PROGMEM`  - это массив, который компилятор с линкером затолкают во флеш-память. А для этого им в момент компиляции надо знать содержимое и размер этой вашей str.

Искать документацию на http-библиотеку мне лень, но из представленного здесь вижу следующий выход:

- скопировать "страницу" по частям в буфер библиотеки (адрес начала буфера - `ether.tcpOffset()`, смещение считать самостоятельно, по длине скопированных данных
- вызвать `ether.httpServerReply()`